# Laravel sanctum Api working fine when already exists user hit Api but not working with new user

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-10

I'm New in Laravel I have recently created sanctum authentication it is working fine Its creating a valid token when excisting user post the api but when new user try to post the api  token id is invalid

I Have tried to check all things I came to know that tokenable_id is not generating and in validator it return id = 0 and remaining is returning everything fine

{
"message": "Unauthenticated."
}

here is my laravel function in controller

```
`\public function store(Request $request) { $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 'phone_no' => 'required|digits:10', 'name' => 'sometimes|string|nullable', // Allow empty name 'address' => 'sometimes|string|nullable', // Allow empty address 'longitude' => 'sometimes|string|nullable', // Allow empty longitude and latitude 'latitude' => 'sometimes|string|nullable', // Allow empty longitude and latitude 'accuracy' => 'sometimes|string|nullable', // Allow empty longitude and latitude 'referby_coupon' => 'sometimes|string|nullable', // Allow empty referby_coupon ]); // Check for existing user with the same phone number $user = UserModel::where('phone_no', $request->phone_no)->first();

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 422,
        'errors' => $validator->messages()
    ], 422);
} else {
```

```
    if ($user) {
          $user->name = $user->name === 'new' ? '' : $user->name;
            $user->address = $user->address === 'new' ? '' : $user->address;
            $user->longitude = $user->longitude === 'new' ? '' : $user->longitude;
             $user->latitude = $user->latitude === 'new' ? '' : $user->latitude;
              $user->accuracy = $user->accuracy === 'new' ? '' : $user->accuracy;
             $user->referby_coupon = $user->referby_coupon === 'new' ? '' : $user->referby_coupon;
              $token = $user->createToken($request->id)->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 422,
            'message' => 'User already exists',
            'token' => $token,
            'data' => $user
        ], 422);
    } else {
        // Generate random coupon
        $coupon = $this->generateRandomCoupon();

    $user = UserModel::create([
            'id' => $request->id,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'phone_no' => $request->phone_no,
            'address' => $request->address,
            'longitude' => $request->longitude,
            'latitude' => $request->latitude,
            'accuracy' => $request->accuracy,
            'own_coupon' => $coupon, // Insert the generated coupon here
            'referby_coupon' => $request->referby_coupon,
        ]);

        if ($user) {
         $token = $user->createToken($request->id)->plainTextToken;

            return response()->json([
                'status' => 200,
                'token' => $token,
                'message' => 'User Created Successfully'
            ], 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 500,
                'message' => 'Something went wrong'
            ], 500);
        }
    }
}
```

```
}

private function generateRandomCoupon($length = 4) { $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'; $excludedWords = ['CAT', 'DOG']; // Add any words you want to exclude here $coupon = '';
do {
    $coupon = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $coupon .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
} while (UserModel::where('own_coupon', $coupon)->exists() || in_array($coupon, $excludedWords, true));

return $coupon;
```

}`

this is model class

`

```
protected $table = 'users';
<?php

namespace App\Models; use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens; use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable; use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory; use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable; use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken as SanctumPersonalAccessToken;

class UserModel extends Authenticatable { use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'name',
    'phone_no',
    'address',
    'longitude',
    'latitude',
    'accuracy',
    'own_coupon',
    'referby_coupon',
    
    
];

protected $primaryKey = "id";

public $timestamps = false;
```

}`

for excepting user the token work properly but it's not working properly if new user tries to login it saying token id unauthorized.

When a already exiting user try to hit api I am getting response

[image]

this is postman get users request with barer token for new user created
[image]

Comment: Did you set Barar token on the header?

Comment: yes this error is from laravel side ....